# Can't install pywin32 package for Python 3 using pip

Tags: python, pip

When trying to install pywin32 for Python 3.6.1 using pip I get this output:

> C:\Program Files\Python 3\Scripts>pip install pywin32
>
> Collecting pywin32
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for pywin32

What is the problem?

Comment: Install the binary directly: [pywin32](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32)

Comment: Please run `python --version` and post the exact version of python.

Comment: If you have admin rights, installing using the unofficial windows binaries in probably best as mentioned by @peter-wood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a pip pywin32 package for python 3.4. If you take a look at this page: url https://pypi.python.org/simple/pywin32/, you can see that there is a 214_download_url. This indicates that version 214 is the latest available, and the 214 download directory here does not contain an installer for anything later than python 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Try this

Comment: According to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32/220, this is now available for python 3.6.